# Which class should be Singleton in WPF, MVVM structure?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I know my question is subjective and context dependent, but being a beginner to MVVM, I came to know that generally one of the MVVM class is made singleton. Can anybody please tell me if I have Model, ViewModel and View class, generally people prefer which class as singleton and why is it so?

Comment: Which... class? There question is so vague it's almost nonsensical. Nothing in the MVVM pattern deals with a specific singleton class. Why do you think there is one? Why do you think there is *only* one?

Answer (score 3):

Technically, the `Application` class is really the only "required singleton" in a WPF application, and that's mainly because WPF will create it for you.

Otherwise, I typically avoid singletons in my WPF applications completely - there is no reason to introduce them.

Comment: Curious why the downvote - I'd argue that this is really the *correct* answer...